# React.js and React Router: Browser Unexpected Token Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, react-router-dom

**Context**

I've seen similar questions on here and some of those who've posed the question get a positive outcome, but I haven't had anything work for me thus far. That's why I'm asking this dragged out question, and I hope it helps others.

**Objective**

The objective is to have my express-router route every unmatched url request back to my index.html, and have the html file load up bundle.js, which acts as the compiled React application, and have the React app rendered into the html file's root div.

**The Error (Coming through browser console)**

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     bundle.js:1`

**Project Directory**

```
public:
index.html
/dist
 -bundle.js

client:
index.js
/src
 -App.jsx

server:
index.js

package.json
webpack.config.js
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "just-gifs",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/marlonaesparza/just-gifs-js.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/marlonaesparza/just-gifs-js/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/marlonaesparza/just-gifs-js#readme",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon ./server/index.js",
    "build": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "sequelize": "^6.21.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ["regenerator-runtime/runtime.js", __dirname + '/client/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: __dirname + '/node_modules',
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic'}], '@babel/preset-env'],
              plugins: ['babel-plugin-styled-components']
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

***server/index.js***

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/../.env'});
require('./../database/index');

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const homeRouter = require('./api/home');


const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());


app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../public`));
app.use('/api/home', homeRouter);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port: ${port}`);
});
```

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JustGIFs</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***client/index.js***

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/state/store';
import App from './src/App';


const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

**client/src/App.jsx**

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './routes/Home';
import Focus from './routes/Focus';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/homes' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/focus/*' element={<Focus/>} />
        <Route path='*' elemetn={'Not Found Bro'} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};


export default App;
```

**Conclusion**

These files alone make up the error I'm experiencing, and I can't seem to find the bug. For a more thorough analysis, I've linked the Github branch below. Thank you.

Github branch: *https://github.com/marlonaesparza/just-gifs-js/tree/refactor-frontend*

Comment: Try change client/index.js to client/index.jsx